# How to plot large dataset of categorical data?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I plot the below categorical data given that there are over 4119 cities?

```
print(len(city))        #4119
print(len(customers))   #4119
```

`city` looks like: `["San Francisco","London","Paris"]`
`customers` looks like: `[1, 2, 200]`

**This code definitely can't run with so many categories**

```
# %matplotlib inline
# plt.style.use('ggplot')
# x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(city)]
# plt.bar(x_pos, customers, color='green')
# plt.xlabel("City")
# plt.ylabel("Customers #")
# plt.title("Number of customers per city")
# plt.xticks(x_pos, customers)
# plt.show()
```

Comment: is the `city` variable only containing unique values or are there duplicates? What is the results of `np.unique(city).size`?

Comment: ```np.unique(city).size``` is 4119

Comment: Since you are dealing with geographical data perhaps it makes more sense to plot on a map?